# mount a drive when rsync connects to server

Tags: linux, rsync, mount

Background first:
I am working ~120km from home and therefore live in a apartment during the week.
I want to sync my NAS at home to a large (and cheap) HDD I use in the apartment.
Trouble is: The NAS is a WHS-NAS thats getting quiet slow and needs to be replaced sometime soon.
Good news is: There is a Linux-Server (openSUSE) running 24/7.

So my idea was:
Mount alle the relevant NAS-shares on the linux-server and then sync from there.
That works fine except for the powermanagement.
If I don't use the NAS the powermanagement kicks in and sends it to StandBy.
If that happens while the shares are mounted, the next rsync will believ that the folders are empty (because the mount points still exist but have no data)

Currently I log in via SSH and make sure everything is mounted before syncing, but that is just quick and dirty.
I could change the powermanagement to 24/7, but that would be quick and expensive and dirty.

I am here searching for a clean solution. My idea was, as title suggests, that the linux-server should recognize a rsync-login and react to it by waking the NAS and mounting the shares.
I have some scripts, that would do the job, but I can't find a place for them to put, so they would be called on a rsync-login.

Flow of my idea would be something like
Client.RSYNC.Connect --> Server.RSYNC.Receive --> NAS.Wake --> Server.NAS.Mount --> Server.RSYNC.Connected/Disconnect(if NAS unavailable)

Is something like that even possible or does someone have a good solution for the problem (except a 24/7-NAS and manual work)

Kind regards
Ingo

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running OpenSUSE >12.2  with systemd you can create a systemd socket for an rsync server with a preexec that mounts the NAS.